# Insert a new row using JpaRepository in java

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am very new to spring JPA. I have following entity class which I want to insert in table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "user")
    private String user;
}
```

I have an empty table named `test`. I have multiple objects of Test and I want to insert it to the table. For this I have created a repo class:

```
@Repository("testRepo")
public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<Test, String> {
//write insert query    
    @Modifying
    @Query(//What insert query I should write)
    void insertData(@Param("id") String id);

}
```

I have searched but getting only options for update query.

Comment: This is Spring Data JPA (!= JPA API)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your service class do something similar to below.
You don't have to write a separate method to save the entity. save method of the repository can be used to save the entity.

```
class TestDAO{

@Autowired
TestRepo testRepo;

public void saveTest(Test test) {
testRepo.save(test);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The method `.save(Entity entity)`, inherited from the Parent interface `CrudRepository` can be used to both update an existing entity or create a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Your repository interface extends from JpaRepository which extends from *CrudRepository*. **save** and **saveAndFlush** methods can be used as default to insert new rows.

***save:*** Inserts new rows. You can give row list as parameter to this method. In your example it should be used like this:

```
testRepo.save(testEntity);
```

or

```
testRepo.save(testEntities);
```

***saveAndFlush:*** Inserts only a new row and commit the changes immediately.
In your example it should be used like this:

```
testRepo.saveAndFlush(testEntity);
```

Answer (score 0):

("insert into table values (?1)",nativeQuery = true)

Answer (score 0):

Using spring boot 2.7.5 I'm using JPA Repository with this for instance:

```
    @Query("INSERT INTO Planeta p (nome, clima, terreno) VALUES (:nome, :clima, :terreno)")
    Integer insertPlaneta(String nome, String clima, String terreno);
```

Parameters are passed with :name_of_parameter according with parameters method.